# Kable caption in rmarkdown file in HTML in bold

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I want to make my table caption in bold but can't seem to find the option for it.

My code is (in a rmarkdown document):

```
kable(head(iris), caption = 'I want this in Bold') %>% 
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive"))
```

The output is:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Does this markdown-oriented solution work for you?

````
```{r, results='asis'}
kable(head(iris), caption = '**I want this in Bold**') %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed","responsive"))
```
````

---

for `html`-output this should work:

````
```{r, results='asis'}
kable(head(iris), caption = '<b>I want this in Bold</b>', format = 'html') %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed","responsive"))
```
````

---

for `pdf`-output this should work:

````
```{r, results='asis'}
kable(head(iris), caption = '\\textbf{I want this in Bold}', format = 'latex') %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed","responsive"))
```
````

Comment: it does not work when I pipe it into ``kable_styling``.. Without the latter it works...

Comment: would you be so kind as to tell me what the desired output-format of your complete file is?

Comment: it is html, I use ``html_document``

Comment: Great! Thanks! What does ``results='asis'`` do? It seems to work without...

Comment: It does not matter using `kable`, you're right. It's usage is only really relevant when you're generating html-code in the code-chunk.

Comment: Thanks, @MaxTeflon for your clear answer. By any chance, do you know how I can center the caption? with this method, the caption is on the left side of the table

Comment: if you are generating pdf or html-output, you could append the generated code, `{\centering....}` for latex and `<center>...</center>` for html.