# Markdown > html : Centering a table caption

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

- How can I center the caption of a table in Markdown to html with `kable` ?
- Is there anyway to put the caption below the table ?

I am using `kable` and `kable_styling`

```
        aaa = matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), nrow = 3)
        print(kable_styling(kable(xtable(aaa), 
    caption = "A very very very very long caption that should be centered 
   rather than left aligned",  col.names = c("col1","Col2"), 
   digits= 2, format = "html", align = "c", 
   row.names = FALSE, booktabs = TRUE), bootstrap = 'striped', full_width = T))
```

I tried to adapt what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56951752/kabel-caption-in-rmarkdown-file-in-html-in-bold) by adding `<center>`before the caption. The caption was centered but the label "Table ... : " was not.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your chunk information `"{r, ...}"`, there is an option `fig.cap` ==> `"{r, fig.cap="Title information"...}"`.
You can use it for any type of caption.

Is it work for you ?

Comment: No, it is not working in my case. The table comes from a loop that produces few tables (and graphs) in a unique chunk. Moreover, I also want to put the caption below my table.